# Certificates and Provisioning Profiles for Push Notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I'm having trouble with the process. I have got push notifications working for **Development**. I **have** read multiple guides and questions, and for some reason - either their guides are deprecated in iOS 8 or my Xcode is bugged - I am having issues with provisioning profiles.

For the purposes of this question, I have generalized most of the terms for privacy concerns.

I'm currently greeted with the bug - **Failed to code sign "App"**. There is a **Fix Issue** button, but I made sure I did not click that; I'm afraid it'll only complicate my problems.

[image: Failed To Code Sign Screenshot]

I've followed the [Parse iOS Notifications Guide](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) and configured my app according to the guide. I've done the following:

1. Requested a **certificateSigningRequest** from Keychain Access
2. Created a new **App ID** in **iTunes Connect**, with a new bundle identifier. I made sure I went into my `info.plist` in my app to change and match the new **App ID** created in **iTunes Connect**.
3. Using the new **App ID** in **iTunes Connect**, I created the **Production SSL Certificate**. [image: SSL Certificate Screenshot]
4. Installed it to my **KeyChain Access**, and exported it to upload to Parse.

Next, I deal with the Provision profile. Once again, I went in **iTunes Connect**, created a new provisioning profile, made sure to link the correct **bundle ID** with it, and downloaded it.

Here comes the part that may have fudged up the process. In the **Parse Notifications Guide**, they instructed users to double click the downloaded file - in my case, it was called "AdHocDistribution.mobileprovisioning", which will install itself into Xcode.

> Download the generated provisioning profile from the next screen by selecting the "Download" button.
>
> Install the profile by double-clicking on the downloaded file.
>
> This should open Xcode's Organizer in the Devices pane. Your new provisioning profile should appear in the Provisioning Profiles section of your Library. Make sure that the status for this profile is "Valid profile". If the profile is invalid, make sure that your developer certificate is installed in your Keychain.

Double clicking the **mobileprovisioning** file did not lead to any discernable feedback telling me that it was installed.

Finally, I modified the **code signing** fields in my project and target's build settings to match the one I downloaded.

[image]

Finally, I try running the app, and the error popped up. Please help!

Comment: Did you installed production certificate in keychain which is used to create ad hoc provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a provisioning profile of the application using ADHOC from dev account.Download and control drag it to Xcode, Under provisioning profile in your screenshot select that.
Do the same for Target and project and you will be good to go!

P.S. also select the Team as your dev account

Comment: This solved the code signing, but I was greeted with a "process launch failed: failed to get task for process: 1859"

Comment: You cannot Run in Simulator OR device in DEBUG mode using this settings, this is for generating the IPA and installing the app via TestFlight, For running in device via Debug you need to create the development profile and config your application bundle for development push notification.
Hope could make you understand

Comment: I was running this on my device. I'm not sure if it's in DEBUG mode. How do I check? And how can I make the switch to distribution mode?

Comment: You are running it in your device hooked in Xcode, yeah that is DEBUG mode. Distribution or Ad hoc mode as mentioned in your settings is when you install the app from TEST Flight not from hooking it up with your mac

Comment: oh boy. Well, thank you very much for your help. This problem has burdened me for 2 whole days. Very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps..

1. Check all your targets's Code signing Section. Like Project and Test Target.
2. Check the project "identifier" in all your .Plist file.
3. Add the account in Xcode Account section, by choose from :
   XCode-> Preference - > Account -> click on +sign and add your apple developer account.

Hope it will help you.